Google Routes API in .NET Suddenly started returning empty
Up until recently, the following code was working and returned Travel Routes from the routing API.

        string routesAPIurl = "https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(routesAPIurl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        //request.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers["X-Goog-Api-Key"] = "***************************";
        request.Headers["X-Goog-FieldMask"] = "routes.legs.steps.transitDetails";


        //create transitObject
        TransitObject transitO = new TransitObject();
        transitO.travelMode = "TRANSIT";
        transitO.departureTime = DateTime.Parse("2024-04-17T09:30:00.000Z");
        transitO.computeAlternativeRoutes = true;
        Origin trnOrigin = new Origin();
        trnOrigin.address = "********";
        transitO.origin = trnOrigin;
        Destination trnDestination = new Destination();
        trnDestination.address = "********";
        transitO.destination = trnDestination;
        TransitPreferences transitPreferences = new TransitPreferences();
        transitPreferences.routingPreference = "TRANSIT_ROUTING_PREFERENCE_UNSPECIFIED";
        transitPreferences.allowedTravelModes = new string[] { "LIGHT_RAIL", "BUS" }.ToList();
        transitO.transitPreferences = transitPreferences;


        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transitO));
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }


        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

Here are the objects referred to in the code:

    public class Destination
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Origin
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransitObject
    {
        public Origin origin { get; set; }
        public Destination destination { get; set; }
        public string travelMode { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime departureTime { get; set; }
        public bool computeAlternativeRoutes { get; set; }
        public TransitPreferences transitPreferences { get; set; }
    }

    public class TransitPreferences
    {
        public string routingPreference { get; set; }
        public List<string> allowedTravelModes { get; set; }
    }


As I run it today, it returns empty {}
Does anyone know why this would have suddenly stopped working? I cannot find anything on Google API docs that suggest updates or changes that would cause it to just suddenly return {}
Thanks in advance
I have checked my google api billing and balance is good.
I have tried changing various fields with no luck.
The code  above was last confirmed working about a month ago.

Ok I figured it out but I am leaving the question and Setting the answer to help anyone else who missed it.
Google will simply return 200 empty without much help, but I realised that the departure time was hardcoded, and needed to be set to always be in the future, as past travel routes are empty.
I have now written some code to generate a departure time always in the future and it is working again
